# How do I write an instance for Data.Data ignoring some field?

Tags: haskell

I have following datatype:

```
data My a = Constr a Int String Float VariousComplexTypes ...
```

I want to be able to call `over template (+1)` on it to change all `Int` fields in this data type and down the road. However, I can't request `a` to be an instance of `Data` (its constructors are hidden). At the same time, I don't really interested in changing it with `over template` call, so I tried to write an `instance Data (My a)` manually, making it ignore first field of type `a`, but failed. The following code

```
instance Data (My a) where
  gunfold k z _ = k (k (k (z Constr)))
  toConstr _ = con
  dataTypeOf _ = ty

con = mkConstr ty "Constr" [] Prefix
ty = mkDataType "Mod.My" [con]
```

produces following error:

```
• No instance for (Data a) arising from a use of ‘k’
• In the first argument of ‘k’, namely ‘(k (z Constr))’
  In the first argument of ‘k’, namely ‘(k (k (z Constr)))’
  In the expression: k (k (k (z Constr)))
   |
61 |   gunfold k z _ = k (k (k (z Constr)))
```

Is this possible at all? What other options do I have, except writing all the boilerplate by hand?

Comment: Show us your failed instance, and the exact error you get from it.

Comment: @DanielWagner Done. Not sure what wasn't clear in previous revision of the question, though.

Comment: @arrowd, the error increases the question's discoverability *a lot* (when something isn't working right, google the error message!). It's also like a checksum that our hypothesis about what is going on is correct. We also get more than enough people essentially asking us volunteers to do their homework for them, so including all relevant details to make it a high-quality question is a sign of good faith.

Comment: @luqui Being a member for 9 years, I know all these things and agree with them. However, this specific `No instance for (Data a)` error can happen to various reasons, so it is exactly for the sake of discoverability I wrote `instance`, `Data.Data`, `ignore` and `field` in the question title. I still believe that my question was OK and didn't deserve downvotes (which weren't even been retracted after the edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably get away with:

```
instance Typeable a => Data (My a) where
  gfoldl k z (Constr a x1 x2 x3)
    = z (Constr a) `k` x1 `k` x2 `k` x3
  gunfold k z _ = k . k . k . z $ Constr undefined
  toConstr _ = con
  dataTypeOf _ = ty
con = mkConstr ty "Constr" [] Prefix
ty = mkDataType "Mod.My" [con]
```

which allows for:

```
> gmapT (mkT ((+1) :: Int -> Int)) $ Constr ["list","of","strings"] 10 "foo" 18.0
Constr ["list","of","strings"] 11 "foo" 18.0
> gmapT (mkT ((+1) :: Int -> Int)) $ Constr (123 :: Int) 10 "foo" 18.0
Constr 123 11 "foo" 18.0    -- note: 123 passes through
```

See below for a variation to use if the offending type `a` isn't the first constructor parameter.

Note that `gunfold` barely matters.  See `fromConstr` and `fromConstrB` for how it's used.  Here, the `undefined` is no worse than what `fromConstr` already does.

What really matters is `gfoldl`.  (Note that even though it's not required in the minimal definition, the default implementation is useless for a data type with internal structure that you actually want to operate on, so you're supposed to define it yourself for all non-trivial data structures.)  Here, I've just written it so that the `a` parameter is passed through the fold, allowing the rest to be processed by the `k` function.

If the `a` type appears as something other than the first constructor parameter or you have multiple such types that you want to pass through untouched, you'll need something more general, like:

```
data My a b = Constr Int a String b Double deriving (Show)
instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Data (My a b) where
  gfoldl k z (Constr x1 a x2 b x3)
    = z go `k` x1 `k` x2 `k` x3
    where go y1 y2 y3 = Constr y1 a y2 b y3
  gunfold k z _ = k . k . k . z $ go
    where go y1 y2 y3 = Constr y1 undefined y2 undefined y3
  toConstr _ = con
  dataTypeOf _ = ty
con = mkConstr ty "Constr" [] Prefix
ty = mkDataType "Mod.My" [con]
```

giving:

```
> gmapT (mkT ((+1) :: Int -> Int)) $ Constr 10 (123 :: Int) "thing" [1,2,3] 3.1415
Constr 11 123 "thing" [1,2,3] 3.1415
```

Comment: This works, indeed! So, `undefined` was the way to go. I still don't understand how it works, though. Many thanks for the answer and `gfoldl` note.

Comment: A bit later I bumped into the case where `a` I want to ignore isn't first constructor's parameter. Thanks for covering this case in your answer. I'd upvote it twice or even dozen of times, if I could!